# Importing SQL file to HeidiSQL

Tags: mysql, heidisql

When I try to import the table and datas to HeidiSQL, I am getting two kind of errors.

1. When Load SQL file and select "Run files(s) directly", the following popup displays and could not be closed

[image]

2. When Load SQL file and select "Load file(s) into editor", the following error is being displayed.

[image]

Can anyone guide me how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you open the same file in notepad or some other text editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same file must not be opened in another application, otherwise HeidiSQL is not able to apply a file lock here, which results in the above "Stream read error" message. So, make sure the file is not in use by some other application.

Also, file size can matter. On a 32bit Windows there is a chance you get the same error with files with some gb of text in them. The 64bit version of HeidiSQL can solve these issues.

Ah, and if you chose Encoding: "Auto detect" in the file-open-dialog, HeidiSQL may have failed during that auto-detection. Try to select the file-encoding manually.